Unable to upload file from file that in src to cloudnary
In my src directory, there is a temp file, using multer I upload the file in the temp file but I cannot upload the file in cloudinary. Why it happen please help me, please help me
Here is my code:
console.log("file detail:", JSON.stringify(req.file))
 //output {"fieldname":"avatar","originalname":"Screenshot 2024-07-27 004034.png","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"image/png","destination":"uploads/","filename":"Screenshot 2024-07-27 004034.png","path":"uploads\Screenshot 2024-07-27 004034.png","size":474631}
if (req.file) {
  try {
    const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
      folder: "learnify",
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      gravity: "faces",
      crop: "fill",
    }).then(result=>console.log('RESULT',result)).catch(error => {
      console.error(error.message)});// For result i get undefined

    if (result) {
      user.avatar.public_id = result.public_id;
      user.avatar.secure_url = result.secure_url;

      // Remove file from server
      fs.rm(`../temp/${req.file.filename}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new AppError("File not upload, please try again", 500));
  }

I am trying to upload file to cloudnary from temp file...

@harshit, what is the full error log?
You mentioned For result i get undefined but there should be more to that. Can you post the full error?
If you got something like this TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uploader'), there is something wrong with the import.
If you imported it as require('cloudinary').v2, you'll have to omit the v2 in your call - await cloudinary.uploader.upload.

I get this
{
"success": false,
"message": "File not upload, please try again",
"stack": "Error: File not upload, please try again\n    at register
(file:///D:/WorkSpace/Learnify/learnifyserver/controllers/user.controller.js:74:21)\n    at
process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
}
